# why can I not use my package normally? PyPi

Tags: python, pypi

I'm building a very simple package, and I managed to upload it to pypi.
I followed this post: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/build-your-first-python-package/

But when I tried to import it and use it, a weird thing happened.

```
import testsimpleprinter as tsp

tsp.testsimpleprinter("Hello") # <- does not work

tsp.testsimpleprinter.testsimpleprinter("Hello there!") # <- this works just fine
```

```
TestSimplePrinter
├── testsimpleprinter
│   ├── testsimpleprinter.py <- inside this, I have a func called testsimpleprinter again
│   └── __init__.py <- "from testsimpleprinter import testsimpleprinter"
├── setup.py
```

At first I thought i had created `setup.py` somewhere wrong, so I moved it inside testsimpleprinter folder. But when i tried with it I got something like this:

```
ERROR: File "setup.py" not found for legacy project testsimpleprinter==0.1.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/08/36/6446d90277fa8899aaa68b811b/a89ba43807c58be2bab666197ff0e9f41c/testsimpleprinter-0.1.0.tar.gz#sha256=713fc48338620adfd4ef71102478d5e740ad77164fafbc19363f4cf1816922cc.
```

As in the post, I want to use my package like this

```
import testsimpleprinter as tsp

tsp.testsimpleprinter("Hello") # I want it to work
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What did you write in your `testsimpleprinter/__init__.py` file?. Just saw it, please, ignore this.

Comment: Seeing how there are *three* levels with the exact same name, there is a lot of guessing required to figure how you set up the package and code. Please provide a [mcve] to help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your `testsimpleprinter/__init__.py` file. With the import statement `from testsimpleprinter import testsimpleprinter` you are reimporting the package, not the local `testsimpleprinter.py` file. To specify the local file, you need to add a `.` as a prefix, which should be like:

```
# testsimpleprinter/__init__.py file
from .testsimpleprinter import testsimpleprinter
```